# js intellisense in visual studio code not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe I'm missing something, but I've been using visual studio code for angular development for a while now, and while the intellisense of libraries like angular is working, it isn't working for my own javascript code. For example:

```
function Test3() {  
    var _this = this;
    this.doSomething = function (test) {
        return 1;
    }

    // intellisense not working (no suggestions after typing _this):
    _this.doSomething();
}

// intellisense working (intellisense finds test3):
var t = new Test3();

// not suggestions (intellisense doesn't find doSomething() after typing t)
t.doSomething();
```

another example:

```
var service = {};
service.doSomething = function() {
   return 2;
}

// intellisense not working (no suggestions after typing service.)
service.doSomething();
```

I've tried this on several development machines and even now with the latest version (0.9.2) it still doesn't work. Is there some setting I don't know about? All above examples have correct intellisense in VS2013/2015.